# insert postgis geometry with GET values

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to make an insert using ST_Makepoint with get values, but I run into 500 Error.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
try {
    $user = 'user';
    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=userdb', $user);


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table(id_a, id_b, geom) VALUES (?,?,?);");

    if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id_a'], $_GET['id_b'], ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($_GET['lat'], $_GET['long']),4326)))) {
        print_r("OK");
    } else {
        print_r("Error");
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

If I run this query with pgAdmin, it runs well:

```
INSERT INTO table(id_a, id_b, geom) VALUES (1,1,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2, 2),4326));
```

Do you know how to fix the problem in php code?

Comment: in your code, you have this INSERT request: `INSERT INTO table(id_a, id_b, geom) VALUES (?,?,?);` but in your result you are using table `posizioni`, so tried you edit your INSERT to this: `INSERT INTO posizioni(...`

Comment: You have to flip lat & long around. PostGIS always puts long (x) before (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table(id_a, id_b, geom) VALUES (?,?,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?),4326));");

    if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id_a'], $_GET['id_b'], $_GET['lat'], $_GET['long']))) {
        print_r("OK");
    } else {
        print_r("Errore");
    }
```